# How to sum values of one column and group them by another column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
time   type qty
12:00  A    5
13:00  A    1
14:00  B    9
```

I need to sum the values of `qty` and group them by `type`. This is how I do it, but it seems to be not working, because I don't know how to add `qty`.

```
keys = df['type'].unique()
summary = pd.DataFrame()
for k in keys:
    summary[k] = df[df['type']==k].sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupBy has a `sum` method:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("type").sum()
Out[11]:
      qty
type
A       6
B       9
```

see the [groupby docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: How does it know that "qty" column values must be summed up? What happens if I have numerous integer columns, like "qty1", "qty2", etc.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos only numeric types are summed.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you are summing up the column you want to:

```
df.groupby(by=['type'])['qty'].sum()
```